# Как добавить запись в таблицу одним запросом?

Tags: sql, oracle

Есть таблицы.

```
books (BookID, Title)
tags (TagID, TagName)
```

Хочу сделать связанную таблицу для указания тегов относящихся к книге:

```
BookTags (BookId, TagId)
```

Тогда записи в этой таблице будут вида:

```
1 | 2
1 | 3
2 | 3
```

и т.д.

Как добавить запись, если я знаю `BookID` и имя тега `TagName`?

Первое, что пришло в голову это сделать подзапрос внутри `insert` для получения `TagID`. 
Но это невозможно сделать для одного значения, либо для всех вставляемых, либо никак.

Как вариант, перед вставкой делать запрос на `TagID`, но может быть можно сделать вставку одним запросом?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если известны наименование книги и тега, то:

```sql
INSERT INTO BookTags (BookId, TagId)
SELECT Books.BookID, Tags.TagId
FROM Books, Tags
WHERE Books.Title = @BookTitle
  AND Tags.TagName = @TagName;
```

Comment: @Evi Учтите - книги бывают полными тёзками. Отслеживайте это - запрос залепит ВСЕМ книгам-однофамильцам указанный тег, не разбираясь.

Comment: Извините, а вы проверили ваш запрос на работоспособность?

Comment: @0xdb Отсутствие структуры и данных в вопросе не позволяют выполнить проверку на материале автора. А так - да, запрос работоспособен (а при уникальности наименований - ещё и корректно работоспособен).

Comment: Всем спасибо я все доправил как нужно, главное было понять суть, в какую сторону думать

Comment: @0xdb на всякий случай - [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=80180c9c6aec6510278adf0aa4203fda)

Comment: @Akina Опять у меня фиддл украли, ай-яй-яй ;)

Comment: @0xdb Почему украли-то? взял попользоваться и вернул - причём с процентами!

Comment: @Akina  Да попользуйтесь на здоровье! Толку всё равно мало, запрос как был не рабочий, так и остался. ТС он больше не нужен, он уже написал, что всё сам доделал.

Answer (score 2):

Записи в таблицу можно вставлять путем получения данных из другого запроса. Для вашей задачи это будет выглядеть так:

```
insert into BookTags(
  BookTagsId, BookId, TagId)
select
  seq_BookTags.nextval, t.TagID, :BookId
from Tags t
where t.TagName = :TagName
```

Я добавил в таблицу первичный ключ (лучше чтобы он был, но удалите если не требуется).

Через параметры `:BookId`, `:TagName` передаю id книги и имя тега.

Answer (score 2):

Полностью рабочий и воспроизводимый пример:

```sql
var BookId number
var TagName varchar2 (100)
exec :BookId:=1; :TagName:='роман';

insert into BookTags
    select :BookId, tags.id TagId 
    from tags 
    where tags.name=:TagName;

select * from BookTags;

    BOOKID      TAGID
---------- ----------
         1          2
```

`BookId` и `TagName` - это подстановочными переменные в инструменте или приложении.
Тестовые данные для примера на [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=9fd9565fc1c9b2c3fde7497854977110).